# Purchased PS4 with 170 games and cannot log in....help!

Tags: ps4

I purchased a used PS4 for my daughter with 170 downloaded games on the previous account.  My daughter eagerly logged in to play before I had a chance to speak with her and switched the main account to hers and lost access to the original owners games. I have all of his account info to log in again but I have no idea how to correct the log in from her account back to the original.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix!
There are 2 ways to do this. One of the first is to:

1. Make a new account, and login as that user. You will get their games. (However, by getting said account, you violate a rule about selling accounts, so bad bad!)
2. Do a wipe and set that account first thing as the family admin, thus stopping your sis from taking it off. Only family admins can remove family admins, so she can't mess with that again.

Hope I helped!